# PHP Post WMS GetMap Request using XML (GeoServer)

Tags: geoserver, wms, php, xml

I need to be able to 'post' some XML to Geoserver WMS GetMap and get an image back.
I have some valid XML which I can test using the 'demo' feature on Geoserver and it returns an image as expected.

However, I can't seem to figure out the mechanism I need to use to generate the same request and response in PHP.

I have tried using cURL (as I already use successfully for WFS requests) and have had a play with fputs but I can't seem to crack it.

Does anyone have a working example of a WMS GetMap 'Posted' XML request to GeoServer using PHP?

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: you might have more success asking on stackoverflow (or other php site)

Answer (score 2):

Plesae see the code below for an example of how to use curl for getting items from geoserver using xml, php and curl.

```
<?php

  $xml_builder = '
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <ogc:GetMap xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
                        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                        version="1.2.0"
                        service="WMS">
                    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0">
                    <NamedLayer>
                     <Name>myNs:roads</Name>
                     <NamedStyle>
                      <Name>simple_roads</Name>
                     </NamedStyle>
                    </NamedLayer>
                    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
                    <Output>
                     <Format>image/png</Format>
                     <Size>
                     <Width>600</Width>
                     <Height>320</Height>
                     </Size>
                    </Output>
                    <Exceptions>application/vnd.ogc.se+xml</Exceptions>

</ogc:GetMap>
                 ';
  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/GeoServer/wms');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  // Print CURL result.
  echo $ch_result;
?>
```

Obviously you will need to change the XML to suite the layer ect you are after.
You will also need to change the URL in the curl_init to your server if it isn't on localhost from the server perspective.

If it all works a lot of weird text should be printed as it is an image returned. Sometimes you can see the PNG in text up the top as it is part of the png header.